# how to get search attrbutes of all workflows within a namespace

Tags: temporal-workflow

how to get search attrbutes of all workflows within a namespace or taskQueue (don't want to give workflow id) by an external client? I am using Java SDK.

Below is a sample code for workflow and adding search attributes. In the code, WorkflowExecution is used to get search attributes but workflow id was a must as input parameter. I am looking for a solution to get all workflows & search attributes of a namespace without providing a workflow id.

WorkflowServiceStubs service = WorkflowServiceStubs.newInstance();

```
WorkflowClientOptions clientOptios =
    WorkflowClientOptions.newBuilder().setNamespace("samples-namespace").build();

WorkflowClient client = WorkflowClient.newInstance(service, clientOptios);

WorkerFactory factory = WorkerFactory.newInstance(client);

Worker worker = factory.newWorker(TASK_QUEUE);
worker.registerWorkflowImplementationTypes(MyClass.MyWorkflowImpl.class);

worker.registerActivitiesImplementations(new MyClass.MyActivitiesImpl());

factory.start();

String workflowID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

WorkflowOptions workflowOptions =
    WorkflowOptions.newBuilder()
        .setTaskQueue(TASK_QUEUE)
        .setWorkflowId(workflowID)
        .setSearchAttributes(generateSearchAttributes())
        .build();

HelloSearchAttributes.GreetingWorkflow workflow =
    client.newWorkflowStub(MyClass.MyWorkflowImpl.class, workflowOptions);
```

WorkflowExecution execution = WorkflowExecution.newBuilder().setWorkflowId(workflowID).build();

DescribeWorkflowExecutionRequest request = DescribeWorkflowExecutionRequest.newBuilder()
.setNamespace(client.getOptions().getNamespace())
.setExecution(execution)
.build();

```
    DescribeWorkflowExecutionResponse resp =
        service.blockingStub().describeWorkflowExecution(request);
```

SearchAttributes searchAttributes = resp.getWorkflowExecutionInfo().getSearchAttributes();

Answer (score 1):

You want to use ListWorkflowExecutions operation to list workflows using search attributes. The following works for me:

```java
    WorkflowServiceStubs service = WorkflowServiceStubs.newInstance();

    ListWorkflowExecutionsResponse listResult =
        service
            .blockingStub()
            .listWorkflowExecutions(
                ListWorkflowExecutionsRequest.newBuilder()
                    .setNamespace("default")
                    .setQuery("CustomIntField=1")
                    .build());
```